# phpmailer sent inline images as attachment

Tags: phpmailer

when I try to send emails with phpmailer, it send inline images as attachment. I mean before opening email for example in yahoo or gmail , they show that this email has attachment and when I open the mail, it shows images inline and in their right position with no problem,
but I see many emails with inline images that show emails as one that don't have any attachment.
by the way for embedding images to phpmailer I use this method: addEmbeddedImage(filename,cid)

what can I do to solve this problem?
thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach images to an email, they are attachments, no matter what. If you use them by referring to their `cid` values from within your HTML, they will render inline *as well*, but they will still be shown as attachments, because they are. If you refer to images using remote URLs, they will render inline as well (providing you allow your mail client to do so), and they will not show as attachments - that is what the other messages you're seeing will be doing. Generally speaking, referring to images remotely is preferable to embedding/attaching.

Comment: Even if remote images are better, but most email programs will block remote images unless you tell the client to accept them. Which is annoying when sending email confirmations to new users/clients.